# MySQL query - select entries not older than a time period

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM content
  WHERE topic='$rw09[id]' AND active='1' AND date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
  ORDER BY cpc DESC, id DESC
  LIMIT 4
```

The key part of my query is `date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)`. It returns me entries older than a week.  What i want it to return me is entries NOT older than 1 week. How can i modify it to return me desired result?

Thank you.

Comment: make it `>` from `<`...!!!

Comment: Well if they are not older, then they are newer?

Comment: You should also add some [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) in there to avoid severe [injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I am having troubles believing that this is actually a question.

Comment: I didnt realize how DATE_SUB works. Now i do. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried with

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE topic='$rw09[id]' AND active='1' AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
ORDER BY cpc DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 4
```

?